# Why does the traversal result changes after a by-step and keeps only one result?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3, graph-traversal

I'm building an API to fetch and organize some information on my janusgraph database, but I'm relatively new to gremlin queries. I would like to know why a traversal in the second by-step of a group-step returns some incomplete info about the graph

The queries are sent from gremlin python driver as if they are gremlin queries. At first i thought that the problem was something related to it, but then I tried directly from the gremlin terminal (run from bin/gremlin.sh) and the results were the same, so I believe that it is not a bug, but how it is intended to be. That's fine, but I would like to understand why the query results in that and how to build a query that fits my needs.

In the examples I use just one by-step for project-step, but in the real problem I intend to use multiple by-steps like so:

```
(...).project('key1', 'key2', 'key3').by(...).by(...).by(...)
```

Initial configuration:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber')
==>v[1]
==>v[2]

gremlin> g.V(1).in()
==>v[10]

gremlin> g.V(2).in()
==>v[20]


gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber').in()
==>v[10]
==>v[20]
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name').by(project('amount').by(__.in().count()))
==>{fiber={amount=1}}

gremlin> g.V().has('name','fiber').group().by('name').by(__.in().count())
==>{fiber=2}

gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name').by(__.in())
==>{fiber=v[20]}

gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name')
==>{fiber=[v[1], v[2]]}
```

And this is what I was expecting:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name').by(project('amount').by(__.in().count()))
==>{fiber={amount=2}}

gremlin> g.V().has('name','fiber').group().by('name').by(__.in().count())
==>{fiber=2}

gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name').by(__.in())
==>{fiber=[v[10], v[20]]}

gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name')
==>{fiber=[v[1], v[2]]}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've seen, this is simply a design choice in Gremlin and not a bug. The `by()` modulator only calls `next()` on the anonymous `Traversal` passed as its argument and does not bother to iterate the entire thing into a list unless you explicitly tell it to. I don't specifically recall all the reasons why `by(Traversal)` was built to work that way but generally speaking I think it's safer for Gremlin to assume that the user wants the anonymous traversals to do the least amount of work possible. If you want it to do more, then you tell Gremlin you want it to do more.

So for this example:

```
g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name').by(__.in())
```

if you want all the `in()` vertices then you would need to tell Gremlin to explicitly gather that:

```
g.V().has('name', 'fiber').group().by('name').by(__.in().fold())
```

Note that `by()` isn't the only step that works that way and the fact that Gremlin does that least work possible is actually a convenience that can lead to less typing like with `emit()` modulator for `repeat()` step:

```
g.V().repeat(out()).emit(outE())
```

which, in addition to being less to type, reads more nicely than:

```
g.V().repeat(out()).emit(outE().limit(1).count().is(1))
```

I also think that with `by()` (and other steps/modulators that take `Traversal` as an argument) behaving this way, Gremlin doesn't too much of an assumption about what you want the data to look like in the result. If the `Traversal` was always fully iterated it would mean that you would always get a `List` as the output which may or may not be what you want. Then you'd be left to unwrap and throwaway the list - so Gremlin would create an object just to toss it away to GC.

There are probably other reasons (much more specific ones mostly) why `by()` works the way it does, but hopefully this explanation gives you some idea as to why it is the way it is.